# Create updating date array from CSV using papaParse

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object, push

I have the following csv:
Date
7/6/2019
7/7/2019
7/24/2019

New dates will randomly be added to this csv going forward. I am attempting to create an array that will append a newly added date dynamically so that the length of the array continuously grows.

```
var dateArray
var url='gamedates.csv'
function parseData(url, callBack){
Papa.parse(url, {
  download: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    callBack(results.data);
  }});}
parseData(url, createTotalCharts);

//separate out 19 rows from csv file
function createTotalCharts(data){
for (i=1; i<data.length;i++){
dateArray.push(data[i])
}
console.log(dateArray);
};

var dateArray
var url='gamedates.csv'
function parseData(url, callBack){
Papa.parse(url, {
  download: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    callBack(results.data);
  }});}
parseData(url, createTotalCharts);

//separate out 19 rows from csv file
function createTotalCharts(data){
for (i=1; i<data.length;i++){
dateArray.push(data[i])
}
console.log(dateArray);
};
```

Papa Parse parses the csv into rows and each row makes up an array. therefore my single date array turns into for arrays with single items. i am trying to then append each of these items to the dateArray variable. However I keep getting an error that .push of undefined. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var merged=[].concat.apply([],data);
  var array=merged.slice(1);

This changed my array of arrays into a single array which I then sliced. This worked thank you so much.